# How does redirect work in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't have a /charge page. But I do have a subscription/charge page. I was wondering, how do I say, "if a user goes to /charge, redirect them to subscription/charge" using routes

```
No route matches [POST] "/charged"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your routes.rb file to point a url to a specific action

```
get '/charge', to: 'subscription#charge'
```

I'm using something similar to below in my application for post:

```
 match '/charge' => 'subscription#charge', :via => [:post], :as => :subscription_charge
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also write:

```
root 'subscription#charge'
```

and you'll be redirected to the charge page if accessing http://localhost:3000